# Squaring all numbers in a file

Tags: linux, shell-script

Please, can someone share with me, or show me the script for Linux command to read from a file until EOF and compute the square of all numbers read. The result of this computation must be stored in an output file.

Comment: This site is designed for people to help others, not to do the work for them.  You are expected to make sufficient effort in solving it yourself.  I would probably do it with a `for num in...` and use `expr` for the calculation, redirecting its output to the proper file (`>>output`).  Now that you have 80% of the work done, can you complete it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 3.14 >> /tmp/numbers
$ echo 2 >> /tmp/numbers
$ echo 4.0 >> /tmp/numbers

$ awk '{print $1 * $1}' < /tmp/numbers
9.8596
4
16
$ awk '{print $1 * $1}' < /tmp/numbers > /path/to/OutputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ksh93` and `bc` as a compute service, assuming the file `numbers` contain one number on each line:

```
bc -l |&
bc_pid="$!"

while read num; do
    print -p "$num * $num"
    read -p sqr
    printf '%g*%g = %g\n' "$num" "$num" "$sqr"
done <numbers

kill "$bc_pid"
```

The equivalent thing in `bash`:

```
coproc bc -l
bc_pid="$!"

while read num; do
    printf '%g * %g\n' "$num" "$num" >&"${COPROC[1]}"
    read sqr <&"${COPROC[0]}"
    printf '%g*%g = %g\n' "$num" "$num" "$sqr"
done <numbers

kill "$bc_pid"
```